# sheaf of differential forms - tangent sheaf [Hartshorne]

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

I'm reading section 8 Differentials of chapter 2 in Hartshorne. It's is extremely hard to me to understand the nature of the definitions: module of relative differential forms - sheaf of relative differential - tangent sheaf.

It's said that "the sheaf of differential forms is essentially the same as the dual of tangent bundle defined in differential geometry".

I want to understand very explicitly how these constructions come from Diff.Geometry?

Comment: Well just don't read Hartshorne.

Comment: which book have a carefully explanation  about these definitions?

Comment: Crossposted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/132718/sheaf-of-differential-forms-tangent-sheaf-hartshorne

Comment: Try the book of Qing Liu for example.  I'm sure that Goertz-Wedhorn also has a good treatment.

Comment: Thank Adeel, Goertz-Wedhorn's book is really good.